# Is there a command similar to UPSERT, but for SELECT?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-insert

<sup>Let's call it `INLECT` :)</sup>

I am re-starting with SQL and have the typical case of getting the ID of a foreign key in an `INSERT` request

```sql
INSERT INTO countries (best_city_id) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM cities WHERE name="Versailles"))
```

This implies that Versailles is already present in `cities`.

**I would like to do an INLECT™**: `SELECT` the `id` if the condition is met, otherwise `INSERT` a new entry in `cities` and get back the `id`.

This is similar to [`UPSERT`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT) where I either `INSERT` or `UPDATE` a row depending on its existence.

Is this something available in SQL, or do I need to first query for the `id`, check if it is `NULL` and based on that make an extra `INSERT` followed by a new `SELECT` (so up to 4 queries)?

I would prefer to use something portable, but otherwise Postgres will be my platform of choice

Comment: No there is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but this query will always try to insert a new city and you need a unique constraint on the name of the city:

```
WITH city AS (
    INSERT INTO cities(name)
    VALUES ('Versailles')
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
    RETURNING id, name
)
INSERT INTO countries (best_city_id)
SELECT city.id AS best_city_id
FROM    city
UNION
SELECT cities.id FROM cities
WHERE name = 'Versailles';
```

Because of the UNION the second INSERT will always be successful, even when the first INSERT didn't create a new record.

You could also create a function in plpgsql that first does a select and only if it can't find a match, creates a new one. That's up to you.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I am not used to this "bottom-top" approach where you start with an action you expect to fail (and here - the secondary action of inserting a new record), and then go with the main one (the select of the id). I need to keep this in mind. I would have also avoided this kind of approach fearing that it will not be efficient (you always try to insert, the select and then select again), but again - something to get used to. Thanks again, I learned something important.